# Specflow MVC4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, tdd, bdd, specflow

I am new to TDD/BDD and have started a new MVC4 application (I'm new to MVC also) and am trying to work out the steps I need to follow to get myself into all this TDD/BDD mindset.

I have installed Specflow and created a simple feature, view contact. In my feature steps I have a method decorated with BeforeScenario attribute to set up a new datacontext for me to use in my features. In my given I create a contact and add to my datacontext and save.

In my When step I want to navigate to my Client view and in my Then step I want to assert that the client I have create in my Given is displayed on screen.

How can this be done with Specflow as my limited understanding is that I cannot interact with the browser with specflow????

Cheer for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Gojko Adzic's material quite good for this. Have a look at [cuke4ninja](https://github.com/davedf/cuke4ninja) for some really good insights (esp. look at the [web automation](https://github.com/davedf/cuke4ninja/tree/master/src/dotnet/WebNinja) stuff).

Comment: re: Fresh - Surreal, isn't it? It's fairly recent, I remember when it was a site about BDD presented via ninja... but maybe they refocused their efforts?  That or it's a really odd hack, I truly have no idea.  Does anyone know?

Comment: The site got taken down. Luckily it was moved to [github](https://github.com/davedf/cuke4ninja). lmgtfy

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Coypu](https://github.com/featurist/coypu) to interact with the web browser using Specflow.

Coypu is a web driver abstraction i.e. instead of using a specific web driver (e.g. Selenium) you can write web driver agnostic code and then choose the web driver which this code should use (e.g. Selenium, Waitn, PhantomJS HEAD-less browser etc.)

Answer (score 0):

To interact with the browser, check out Selenium [WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#getting-started-with-webdriver).

Here is another [resource](http://www.anujchaudhary.com/2012/11/selenium-automating-ui-testing-for.html) with a "get-started" guide.